# Python and MySQLdb - Using DROP TABLE IF EXISTS seems to throw exception

Tags: python, mysql

I got this code..

```
.....
try:
    task_db.cursor.execute('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `tasks`')
    print "Affected: %d" % task_db.cursor.rowcount 
except MySQLdb.Error, e:
    print "Error ocurred: %s " % e.args[0]
    print e
```

If the tasks table doesn't exist, then I get a warning like

```
create_database.py:11: Warning: Unknown table 'tasks'
```

But if the table does exist then I wont get that warning.
Odd?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's perfectly correct behaviour. If the table exists, then it's dropped. If it doesn't exist then you get *Warning* exception which is not the same as *Error* - you are free to ignore it and nothing bad should happen, but you have to catch it to allow your script to proceed.

EDIT:

To prevent Warning from bubbling up, just catch it as any other exception:

```
try:
    [some code]
except MySQLdb.Warning:
    [exception handling code]
```

Comment: soo... whats a way to prevent that from being displayed in the output?

Comment: Catching MySQLdb.Warning did nothing for me. See [thomdask's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4830497/307705) for alternative fix.

Comment: On further inspection, this code *will* be triggered if you run python with `-Werror` to treat warnings as errors. So it could conceivably make sense to use both solutions together.

Answer (score 23):

Catching the MySQLdb.Warning didn't work for me, so I found another way to suppress warnings:

```
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore", "Unknown table.*")
```

And you can edit the second parameter with whatever you want to suppress.

Answer (score 11):

The most elegant way to avoid Mysql warnings :

```
from warnings import filterwarnings
import MySQLdb

filterwarnings('ignore', category = MySQLdb.Warning)
```

Comment: It is indeed more elegant than thomdask answer but, wouldn't it affect also other warnings we might not want to ignore?

Comment: @Roman, I think that's an important point so I wouldn't say this solution is more elegant.  It's just different, suppressing all warnings vs suppressing one specific warning.